# Enable someone to view an otherwise redirected DotNetNuke site

Tags: dotnetnuke

We have a dotnetnuke installation with a multi-site setup. Don't know if that's the right term, but whatever. One of the sites has been redirected to another per the client's request.

What I was asked to do was to give their admin guy access to the contents of this site, while leaving the redirect in place. I don't even know where to start. Any help would be appreciated.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

That will depend on how the redirection is configured. Have you configured a redirect in IIS perhaps?

If you are using the redirection in DNN (page level) you won't be able to give one person access to the pages, while redirecting all others.

If you are doing the redirection with IIS, you can setup redirects based on domain name, and then provide a different domain name for the admin to access that isn't redirecting.

Comment: No, it's a number of portals (Thanks Nimeshpanda for giving me the right term), some of which are just pointers to others.

Comment: Updated answer with more detail

Answer (score 0):

If I understand the question well, you want that a portal administrator in one site will be the portal administrator for other. You can create a new module and install on the redirected site and pass some encrypted querystring with User Id, read the query string and based on the query string, assign the same user as administrator for the redirected site. You can use the UserController class API of DNN.

Comment: Pretty sure that isn't what he was asking. He wants to allow one user access to a site that all users are redirected for